# How is ASLR supposed to work with coredumps?

Tags: linux, gdb, coredump, aslr

I have a situation where a coredump (generated on a remote system) is not matching symbols in the .o file.   I am suspecting this is due to ASLR.  Unfortunately, I'm not sure how ASLR is supposed to work with coredumps, so I can't verify.

My logic is that because coredump dumps actual memory, the ASLR offsets must be incorporated into the corefile itself (so now, all address reference to function `foo` in the corefile would actually hold `foo.vaddr + aslr_offset`).   gdb would have to know what the aslr offset is in order to translate that address back to `foo`.   I'm not finding the where the aslr offset is stored in the corefile though.   Does anyone know if such a mechanism even exists, and if it does, how it is supposed to work?

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone know if such a mechanism even exists, and if it does, how it is supposed to work?

It *does* exist, as you can trivially verify by creating a local `core` and loading it into GDB.

You can examine the `file` to `segment` mapping in the `NT_FILE` note. It should look like this:

```
eu-readelf -n core

  CORE                 846  FILE
    15 files:
      5645cecd5000-5645cecd6000 00000000 4096        /tmp/a.out
      5645cecd6000-5645cecd7000 00001000 4096        /tmp/a.out
      5645cecd7000-5645cecd8000 00002000 4096        /tmp/a.out
      5645cecd8000-5645cecd9000 00002000 4096        /tmp/a.out
      5645cecd9000-5645cecda000 00003000 4096        /tmp/a.out
      7f6ea8322000-7f6ea8348000 00000000 155648      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
      7f6ea8348000-7f6ea849d000 00026000 1396736     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
      7f6ea849d000-7f6ea84f0000 0017b000 339968      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
      7f6ea84f0000-7f6ea84f4000 001ce000 16384       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
      7f6ea84f4000-7f6ea84f6000 001d2000 8192        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
      7f6ea851c000-7f6ea851d000 00000000 4096        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
      7f6ea851d000-7f6ea8542000 00001000 151552      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
      7f6ea8542000-7f6ea854c000 00026000 40960       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
      7f6ea854c000-7f6ea854e000 00030000 8192        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
      7f6ea854e000-7f6ea8550000 00032000 8192        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

I am not sure that's the mechanism GDB actually uses though.